# Jquery Ajax call from Server side Datatables to Api Controller, 404 error after about 15 minutes of browser inactivity

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, asp.net-core, datatables

I am using asp.net core/jQuery datatables, trying to call an API Controller from view using jQuery Ajax call which works fine but if I leave the browser inactive for about 15 minutes, I get a 404 Not found error for API URL. I am not sure if it has something to do with session expiry, I am using windows authentication and didn't used any explicit cookies or sessions. Could you please help.

My AJAX call is given below.

```
            Vehtable = $('#VehicleTitlesTable').DataTable(
            {
                "processing": true,
                "language": {
                    processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '
                },
                "serverSide": true,
                "filter": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "@ViewData["BaseUrl"]/api/GetVehicleTitlesListApi",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "data": { itemStatus: itemStatus, vehicleId: vehicleId }
                },
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 0,
                    "data": "vehicleTitleId",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a href=@ViewData["BaseUrl"]/VehicleTitles/AddVehicleTitle?vehicleId=' +@ViewData["VehicleId"]+'&titleId=' + data + ' title="Edit" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-edit" style="color:cornflowerblue"></i></a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "targets": 0,
                    "data": "vehicleTitleId",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a href=@ViewData["BaseUrl"]/VehicleTitles/DeleteVehicleTitle?vehicleId=' +@ViewData["VehicleId"]+'&titleId=' + data + ' title="Delete" onclick="return alertPopup()" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:cornflowerblue"></i></a>';
                    }
                }
                ],
                "columns": [
                    {
```

and ApiController starts as follows.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class GetVehicleTitlesListApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SnowmobileATVContext _context;
    private IQueryable<VehicleTitlesViewModel> vehicles;
    private readonly IVehicleTitlesStore _vehicle;
    public GetVehicleTitlesListApiController(SnowmobileATVContext context, IVehicleTitlesStore vehicle)
    {
        _context = context;
        _vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var vehicleId = Request.Form["vehicleId"].FirstOrDefault();
            var itemStatus = Request.Form["itemStatus"].FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: For the 404 page not found error, it usually relates the URL does not correct, try to use F12 developer Network tools to check whether the URL is correct or not. And you could also check if there have redirect? Perhaps the authentication is expired and it redirects to the login page, then meets the 404 error.

Comment: URL is correct because as i mentioned it works fine if you are active in the browser. I didn't used any redirect and i don't have any login page, i am just using windows authentication. i am not sure how can i check if it is a session expire, by the way i have few other views as well which are not server side and they are not using API controller and they are working fine even after an hour. Thanks

Comment: Before and after meet the 404 error, have you ever used the F12 developer Network tools to check whether the URL is different or not?

Comment: Oh yes i just noticed, URL got changed after some time, i think i got it. Thank you very much for your help.